# Scaling Kafka Consumer to 200 Threads without Increasing Partitions (100k Events/15 min)

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, ibm-app-connect

***Context***: I'm building a high-throughput event processing application that needs to handle 100k events within 15 minutes. Currently, this is achieved using 200 parallel threads in IBM MQ within an IBM ACE application on OpenShift Red Hat CloudPak (app takes 9ms to process single event).

***Challenge***: We're migrating to Kafka and want to maintain the same throughput with 200 threads. However, when using Kafka node in IBM ACE message flow as far as i know , if I'm using same group id then I can connect only one thread to one single partition from same consumer group. Increasing partitions to 200 is undesirable due to (administrative overhead, cost).

How can we achieve 100k events/15 min with 200 parallel threads in Kafka without increasing the number of partitions?

Additional Information:

IBM ACE version (12.0.10.0)

IBM MQ 9.3.x

Duplicate message consumption should never occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have more consumers than partitions in a group, but that doesn't mean those consumers are limited to single threads. See https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Comment: thanks for the reply , I'm trying to use unbuilt / out of the box .. Kafka consumer node in IBM ACE toolkit . so , is there any other way to achieve that much amount of parallelism without using that parallel-consumer code? ... I will use the code as a last resort

Comment: I am not familiar with IBM solutions, but the linked repo also uses "out of the box" Kafka Consumer client. https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer/blob/master/parallel-consumer-core/src/main/java/io/confluent/parallelconsumer/ParallelConsumer.java#L11 Otherwise, no, there isn't a different solution than handling thread management on your own, as is written in the Kafka Javadoc.

Comment: Other than that, you're asking to process about 111 events per second (the default `max.poll.records` setting is almost 5x that on 1 thread), which does not really require multithreading, IMO. I feel like I've seen Kafka clusters process thousands of events per second, [even legacy versions](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) and it has [improved since then](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2023/5/15/kafka-vs-redpanda-performance-do-the-claims-add-up)

Comment: Yes , I understand that max.poll.records value is 5x than that . In my scenario  , Correct me if I'm wrong ... the processing time for entire transaction is 10 ms then when i poll say 500 records with single thread then it will take 5 seconds to process all the 500 records for my single thread . that's y i'm asking for parallelism where i wanna process all those 500 records in parallel using all the available threads . Thanks for the repo share , i will implement it as a last resort if there are no solutions at all.

Comment: "Transaction" is an overloaded term here. Kafka producers decide when to start/stop a transaction. It doesn't need to be 500 records and it's often not. I'm not sure I understand where the 10ms number came from? And as answered, you're not required to use 1 thread to process one poll batch. The main issue with distributing that processing, however, is that offset commits happen randomly as threads finish. Meaning "offset 10" thread may finish and commit (skips 1-9), then "offset 2" thread could complete, but override the fact that the consumer group was done with "offset 10"

Answer (score 0):

You can make 20 Topics with each 10 partitions or 10 Topics with each 20 partition.Which will be less overhead to a single topic.
Each thread will assigned to a single partition and will perform much better

Comment: the main issue is 200 partition is undesirable  (administrative overhead, cost etc) and having 20 topics/10 topics with 10 partitions/20 partitions is still almost same as having 200 partitions . The things is , when using MQ even with single node we were able to deliver high throughput to a single consumer  app connecting with 200 threads . When using Kafka , if there are multiple consumer groups /n number of consumers\ groups then we can increase number of partitions as funding will be provided but in our case,there is only one consumer app which needs to consume (~100k within 15 mins)

Comment: Basically , I'm looking for an option to use all of my consumer threads/instances from my app without increasing/adding 100 + partitions . In future , we need to process 1 million records within 15 mins then on that time we can't add 500 partitions for a single consumer .. that's crazy

Comment: For a Single queue 200 threads consumed?? Which MQ has been used before.Im sure creating 10 Topics is less costly. How you are saying creating 200 partitions costly.

So If you are going with kafka for parallel 200 Threads you must have 200 partitions.

Or you shout have some multiple consumer groups consume same topic and process alternatively and skip others.

Comment: each partition is not a separate node. If you have a Kafka Cluster you can created 20 Topics easily which is very very less compared to its potential.You can create more.

Again asking which MQ you have used previously? ```we can't add 500 partitions for a single consumer``` Yes thats why im saying create 20 topics with each 10 partition. So if your message rate increases you can create more topics to distribute.

Comment: ```when using MQ even with single node we were able to deliver high throughput to a single consumer app connecting with 200 threads ``` litrelly what MQ you saying here? In Kafka also you can create 200 partitions and connect an AppServer with 200 Threads consuming that partitions.

Comment: thanks for the reply . I'm using **IBM MQ 9.3.x**.

my view on this , say we have only 3 brokers in our production environment then creating 500 partitions will be heavy on brokers it will impact brokers stability if adequate resource is not provided as rebalancing will be resource intensive across large no of partitions and large no of partitions requires more disk , memory etc.. . so , if we gonna add required resources then it will cost us more .

Comment: My main point, which I forgot to add, is that the traffic won't be consistent like 1111 per second. The input events will be in short burst mode. We will be getting 1 million records in a short time, which we need to process within 15 minutes. Then, we won't be getting any records at all for maybe another 10 hours. When using IBM MQ, during high loads, our app will automatically scale up the number of consumer threads to 200+ when there are a lot of messages in the queue and scale down accordingly as well.

Comment: This means we use fewer resources when required. But if I have 200 partitions in Kafka and 200 consumer threads, even when there are no loads for many hours, the resources are still being used to some extent and won't scale down to extremely minimal levels , the resource are still being used to some extent and it won't scale down to extreme minimal . that's why if i'm able to use limited partitions but if still i'm able to achieve high level parallelism will be wonderful

Comment: You are saying dynamically increase/decrease the Consumer Threads based on the load? which we cannot achieve this with Kafka. 

Lets assume when in Huge Load you need to have 200 Threads which need of some system resourse.After that the threads will be idle.It won't use much of CPU resource and the Threads will be idle.Which won't be big usage of resourse.

You have to allocate some resourse for 200 Threads anyhow. With IBM  he will use the resourse foe other customer when your load is less. While you managing everything that resourse will be idle

Comment: Or else you can dynamically create multiple ConsumerGroups 
example. 20 Partitions 1 CG1 with 10 Threads initially so all the messages processed by 10 Threads in CG1.

when the Load increase 2x Create another CG2 which also consume the same 10 Partitions so each partitions will have 2 Threads.Here CG1 will consume first message and skip 2nd message. CG2 consumer skip 1st message ,consume 2nd Message and Skip 3rd message.

like wise you can increase the ConsumerGroups to acheive parallelism